# Send data from server side to client side Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, server-side

Server side: App.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var fire = require('./Firebase.js')

app.get('/route', function (req, res) {
    fire.getData(req.body, res)
})
```

Server side: Firebase.js

```
var firebase = require('firebase')
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var v = firebase.database();

var users = firebase.database().ref("users");

exports.getData = function(data, res){
    users.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
   //Solution: Array if more values than one.

        var content = '';
        content += '<tr>';
        content +='<td>'+ childData.Firstname + '<td>';
        content +='<td>'+ childData.Lastname + '<td>';
        content += '</tr>';
        res.send(content);
        });
    });   
}
```

Client side: Structure.js

```
$.get("/route", function (response) { 
    console.log(response)
})
```

But the problem is that it's saying I'm trying to call it twice, casting me different error messages. So how can I get the value from server side to client side? It shows the right data in Firebase.js and in App.js whild console.log(...). I have found some posts how to do this, but it doesn't really fit my problem. 
Solution: casting twice or more because I didn't have an array folding the values from the firebase.

Comment: What is $ in Firebase.js?  It doesn't appear to be defined in the code you've posted.  For that matter, neither is `users`.

Comment: sorry, updated it. $ is Jquery. @Paul

Comment: > You're not using jquery on the server as far as I can tell, nor should you.

Comment: I've deleted that part :-)

Comment: Your code is still showing that you're using jquery in the getData function, but jQuery uses the browser window's DOM object.  Unless you're using some kind of headless browser to emulate that (and it doesn't look like you are), it's not going to work.  Even if you do set it up that way, there are far more efficient ways to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've updated. now the Structure.js has the value from the firebase, using an array inside the Firebase.js

Answer (score 2):

you cannot append the data on the server side, that means
you cannot do this on the server
`$('#valuesFromDatabase').append(content);`

Instead, you should do this on the client like this:

```
$.get("/route", function (response) {
    console.log(response)
    $('#valuesFromDatabase').append(response);
    //Code here trying to print out to a table with the id                           
    'valuesFromDatabase' 
})
```

Comment: It prints out the value in the console, but just casting errors: Can't set headers after they are sent. (googled it and people said it was because it tries to cast more than ones)

Comment: Okay, got a help from a friend, and made it to an array :D because I had more values than one!